# How can i get the id of the select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a couple of `select2` 'controls'

```
<select id="SizeID" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"  style="">
        //                          
</select>

<select id="ColorID" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"  style="">
        //                          
</select>
```

By using the following, i can get the selected values.

```
$('select').select2().on("change", function (e) {
    log(e.val);
})
```

But how can i get the id of the `select2` that triggered the change event?

Comment: `this.value`  may be?

Comment: have you tried `this.id`      ?

Comment: $(this).attr("id"); does the trick. Thank you both